# Django multipart ORM query including JOINs

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, orm

I believe that I am simply failing to search correctly, so please redirect me to the appropriate question if this is the case.

I have a list of `orders` for an ecommerce platform. I then have two tables called `checkout_orderproduct` and `catalog_product` structured as:

```
|______________checkout_orderproduct_____________|
| id | order_id | product_id | qty | total_price |
--------------------------------------------------

|_____catalog_product_____|
| id | name | description |
---------------------------
```

I am trying to get all of the products associated with an order. My thought is something along the lines of:

```
for order in orders:
    OrderProduct.objects.filter(order_id=order.id, IM_STUCK_HERE)
```

What should the second part of the query be so that I get back a list of products such as

```
["Fruit", "Bagels", "Coffee"]
```

Comment: I suppose that `product _id` in `checkout_orderproduct` is a foreign key to `catalog_product`. It would be nevertheless useful if you can provide an excerpt from your models.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
products = (OrderProduct.objects
            .filter(order_id=order.id)
            .values('product_id'))
Product.objects.filter(id__in=products)
```

Or `id__in=list(products)`: see note "Performance considerations" [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#in).

Comment: Ok so I am looking at a multi stage query to get this done. There's no single mega query which can do it all?

Comment: Should result be a list of products of all orders or a dictionary like `{order_id: list_or_queryset_of_products}`?

Comment: Preferably a dictionary